# ggplot2 bar chart convert label from seconds to min:sec

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I want to create a bar-chart where the y-axis uses "min:sec" as labels. However, the data I want to display has seconds as units.
What is now the best approach to do this?

```
zone  time_in_zone
   1           305
   2           664
   3          1945
   4          1187
```

I would plot this data using:

```
ggplot(data, aes(fill=zone, y=time_in_zone, x=zone))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

However, I fail converting the y-axis to a meaningful time series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `scale_y_time` to your plot like this...

```
ggplot(data, aes(fill=zone, y=time_in_zone, x=zone))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    scale_y_time()
```

Which should give you a time formatted y axis like this...

[image: plot with time y-axis]

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this new function. Now I only have to update my ggplot to >= 2.2.0